# Java - Program not breaking out of loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
while (choice != 7) { 

    System.out.println("---  Mathematical Calculator  ---");

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Pick an operation from the list - Use nos. 1 to 7");
    System.out.println("1) Multiplication");
    System.out.println("2) Division");
    System.out.println("3) Addition");
    System.out.println("4) Subtraction");
    System.out.println("5) Find the area of a regular object");
    System.out.println("6) Find the volume of a regular object");
    System.out.println("7) Exit");

    choice = userInput.nextInt(); 

    switch (choice) {

    case 1: {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("You have chosen multiplication");
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        double num1 = userInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter another number");
        double num2 = userInput.nextDouble();

        double num3 = num1 * num2;

        System.out.println(num1 + " * " + num2 + " = " + num3);         
        num1 = num3;

        while (choice2 != 5 || choice2 != 6) {

            System.out.println(""); System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("If you would like to build on the answer obtained - pick an operation from the list - Use nos. 1 to 4");
            System.out.println("Else press 5 to return to the main menu");
            System.out.println("1) Multiplication");
            System.out.println("2) Division");
            System.out.println("3) Addition");
            System.out.println("4) Subtraction");
            System.out.println("5) Start new calculation");
            System.out.println("6) Exit");

            choice2 = userInput.nextInt();

            switch (choice2) {

            case 1: 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number");
                num2 = userInput.nextDouble();
                num3 = num1 * num2;
                System.out.println(num1 + " * " + num2 + " = " + num3);
                num1 = num3;
                break;
            }

            case 2: 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number");
                num2 = userInput.nextDouble();
                num3 = num1 / num2;
                System.out.println(num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + num3);
                num1 = num3;
                reak;
            }

            case 3: 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number");
                num2 = userInput.nextDouble();
                num3 = num1 + num2;
                System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + num3);
                num1 = num3;
                break;
            }

            case 4: 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number");
                num2 = userInput.nextDouble();
                num3 = num1 - num2;
                System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + num3);
                num1 = num3;
                break;
            }

            case 5: choice = 0; break;

            case 6: choice = 7; break;

            default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
        choice2 = 0;
    }
    break;
}
```

I've posted a short piece of my code.  My issue is that, when I input 5 or 6 in the second query (`choice2`), my program continues to loop instead of breaking out of the loop and going back to the main menu/ terminating the program.

Would appreciate some feedback on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Your `while (choice2 != 5 || choice2 != 6)` is wrong, since it will always result in true. If choice2 is 5, then the second clause will be true.

Not to mention that you always set choice2 to 0 at the end of the loop, so the loop will continue forever even if you replace `||` with `&&`.

Answer (score 3):

The condition `choice2 != 5 || choice2 != 6` is always true, because there is no number that is equal to 5 and to 6 at the same time.

If you would like to break out of the loop when 5 or 6 is entered, use `&&` instead:

```
while (choice2 != 5 && choice2 != 6)
```

Make sure that `choice2` is set prior to continuing with the next iteration of the loop.

Note that you could break out of the loop from within your `switch` statement by using a labeled break construct:

```
calc: // Label the loop for using labeled break
while (true) {
    ...
    switch(...) {
        case 1:
            break;          // This will exit the switch
        ...
        case 6: break calc; // This will exit the loop
    }
}
```